# Prove that sin(x)/x is not Lebesgue Integrable in [1,+oo]

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone help me on how to prove that sin(x)/x is not Lebesgue Integrable in [1,+00], Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add your thoughts, and maybe your attempts.

Comment: I tried to make a series and show that that series is divergent but im having some trouble figuring out the right series to consider

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\int_{\pi /4}^{3 \pi /4} |\sin x| \, dx >0$. Now consider the integrals over $(2k\pi +\pi /4, 2k \pi +3\pi /4) )$ and add up.

Observe that $|x+2k\pi | <2k \pi  +3\pi /4$ on $(2k\pi +\pi /4, 2k \pi +3\pi /4) )$.

Comment: alright i understand what you are doing , just one question, does |f| not being lebesgue integrable implies that f isnt lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Yes, unlike Riemann integrals, Lebesgue integrals have the property that $f$ is integrable iff $|f|$ is.

Comment: Alright , Thanks.